# Callback function getting called before initial function finishes

Tags: javascript, callback, socket.io

I am having issues with callback functions - I have a main function which has two callback functions inside. This is the main function

```
socket.on('play next video', function(data) {
    removeVideo(cue[0], getCueFromDb(function() {
        io.sockets.emit('next video');
    }));    
});
```

My removeVideo function looks like this:

```
function removeVideo(id, callback) {
Video.find({'id' : id}).remove(function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
    console.log("Removed video", id)
});
if (callback)
        callback();
    else
        return
}
```

and the getCueFromDb function looks like this

```
function getCueFromDb(callback) {
Video.find({}).exec(function(err, videos) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        if (videos.length) {
            cue.length = 0 // empty array
            videos.forEach(function(video) {
                cue.push(video.id) // push all the videos from db into cue array
            });
            io.sockets.emit('send cue', {cue: cue});
        }
        else {
            console.log("No more videos in database!")
        }
    if (callback)
        callback();
    else 
        return
});
```

}

However the functions aren't getting called in the correct order - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: HINT: on this line `removeVideo(cue[0], getCueFromDb(function() {` the 2nd argument to `removeVideo()` is not a callback. You are executing that function instead of passing it as a reference.

Comment: The sockets functions are asynchronous. This means the the JS code execution continues, even if the asynchronous function did not end its execution. You have to include the callback inside the function parameters. http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: `getCueFromDb` doesn't return any callback for second `removeVideo`'s argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback needs to be inside your `find.remove()`

```
function removeVideo(id, callback) {
Video.find({'id' : id}).remove(function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
    console.log("Removed video", id)
    if (callback)
        callback();
    else
        return
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change removeVideo so callback we be called only after delete.

That's the code:

```
 function removeVideo(id, callback) {
    Video.find({'id' : id}).remove(function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        console.log("Removed video", id)

       if (callback)
            callback();
        else
            return
    }
    });
```

So callback will be called only after vide is really removed.